# How do I can pass userDetails as a parameter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, roo

How do I pass Userr instance as a parameter. I have tried this but it's not working.

```
public Double getCurrentProfitAndLoss() {
    Double currentProfitAndLoss = null;
    Userr user = ( (OptionsUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUserr();
    user =  Userr.findUserr(user.getId());
    HomePageService homePageService = homePageServiceFactory.getObject();

    System.out.println("homePageService object  created");
    try {
        currentProfitAndLoss = homePageService.getCurrentProfitAndLoss(user);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return currentProfitAndLoss;
}
```

But when I pass as a single property of Userr like this it works fine.

```
public Double getCurrentProfitAndLoss() {
    Double currentProfitAndLoss = null;
    Userr user = ( (OptionsUser)     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUserr();
    user =  Userr.findUserr(user.getId());
    HomePageService homePageService = homePageServiceFactory.getObject();

    System.out.println("homePageService object  created");
    try {
        currentProfitAndLoss = homePageService.getCurrentProfitAndLoss(user.getId());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return currentProfitAndLoss;
}
```

How do I pass user object?

This is the method accepting user object and I am not getting any error.

public class HomePageService {

```
public Double getCurrentProfitAndLoss(Userr user) {
 System.out.println("iside HOmepageService");
 Double currentProfitPercPA =       StrategyExitReport.findCurrentProfitAndLossById(user);
 System.out.println("iside currentProfitPercPA" + currentProfitPercPA);
 return currentProfitPercPA;
 }
}
```

Comment: Most likely you have to change the signature of the respective method in HomePageService. Make it accept Userr instead of Integer or Long (or whatever type getId() returns).

Comment: I have a method accepting user object . But still its not working But when i pass user.getID() and accept as Long it works. But when I pass User object and accepting as   public Double getCurrentProfitAndLoss(Userr user) stils it doesn't works

Comment: Maybe you could add HomePageService as well so that it is possible to find the reason for your problem. Please be so kind an insert it properly formatted to ease reading.

Comment: sorry @Florian It got submitted before i could complete.

Comment: You have a nice gray "edit" button underneath your question :)

Comment: well its edited now . so could you ans my question now

Comment: Can you post the getCurrentProfitAndLoss in your service method that accepts a user object?Also, what is the error?

Comment: @Periklis Not getting any error .

Comment: I am unable to figure it out . what's going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you use jpa. So you defined the method findCurrentProfitAndLossById that is ends with ById but you actually use the object.
So change the name of the method to

```
findCurrentProfitAndLossByUser
```

have a look at this site http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation